# caching database calls for ajax autocomplete for acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using the instructions in [this github readme file](http://github.com/pboling/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids) (at the bottom) to make ajax calls for autocompleting a list of tags, sort of like what this website does, actually!

It works pretty well, but it seems like it might be a little inefficient, since the list of tags almost never changes.  Does anyone have recommendations on how to make this better?  Like, if I could store a copy of the list of tags in memory somewhere, and just query that copy instead of querying the db?

```
@tags = Tag.restrict_taggable_type("Document").find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:tag]}%"])
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@tags ||= Tag.restrict_taggable_type("Document").find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:tag]}%"])
```

Huh?

Comment: heh, okay.  and then i just set that again whenever the set of tags gets modified, huh?

Comment: Yes. Invalidate it, for instance, every minute, every 60th request, or use an additional query to check for database changes (i.e. by counting tags).